# How to retrieve two SUM() value from two tables based on foreign key and subtract them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

`products table            purchase table                   sale table

+----+---------+    +----+-----------+-------+   +----+------------+--------+
| id | product |    | id | product_id| pieces|   | id | product_id | pieces |
+----+---------+    +----+-----------+-------+   +----+------------+--------+
| 1  | Tyre    |    | 1  |    3      |   5   |   | 1  |     2      |    3   |
+----+---------+    +----+-----------+-------+   +----+------------+--------+
| 2  | Switch  |    | 2  |    1      |   3   |   | 2  |     1      |    2   |
+----+---------+    +----+-----------+-------+   +----+------------+--------+
| 3  | Ring    |    | 3  |    2      |   6   |   | 3  |     3      |    3   |
+----+---------+    +----+-----------+-------+   +----+------------+--------+                                | 4  | Wheel   |    | 4  |    3      |   4   |   | 4  |     2      |    1   |
+----+---------+    +----+-----------+-------+   +----+------------+--------+`

1. I want to `SUM()` both pieces column in purchase table and sale table based on/GROUP BY product_id. Ex- `SELECT products, SUM(pieces) FROM purchase GROUP BY product_id` Same query for sale table.
2. I want to subtract the `SUM()` result to find out the remaining pieces. Ex-  `SUM(purchase.pieces) - SUM(sale.pieces) AS balance`
3. And finally I need product name from products table, total pieces of same product in purchase table that means how many times a product has been sold such as Tyre - 5 pieces, same for sale table, and remaining pieces after subtract total sale of a product from total purchase of a product.

How can I do this using `PHP` and `PDO`?

Comment: did you consider joins?

Comment: yes, because i need product name from products table

Comment: well just go on with your joins, group by and sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use SUM() for the pieces column and have the difference to get the balance

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.product,
       IFNULL(total_purchase,0) total_purchase,
       IFNULL(total_sales,0) total_sales,
       IFNULL(total_purchase,0) - IFNULL(total_sales,0) balance
  FROM (SELECT pd.id,
               pd.product,
               SUM(pc.pieces) total_purchase
          FROM products pd
          LEFT JOIN purchase pc
            ON pd.id = pc.product_id
         GROUP BY pd.id, pd.product
       ) p
  JOIN (SELECT pd.id,
               pd.product,
               SUM(sl.pieces) total_sales
          FROM products pd
          LEFT JOIN sales sl
            ON pd.id = sl.product_id
         GROUP BY pd.id, pd.product
       ) s
    ON p.id = s.id
 ORDER BY p.id
```

[Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be3e88/2)

```
id  product total_purchase  total_sales balance
1   Tyre    3               2           1
2   Switch  6               4           2
3   Ring    9               3           6
4   Wheel   0               0           0
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should be a good start:

```
select 
products.product
purchases.Total as PurchasedPieces,
sales.Total as SoldPieces
purchases.Total - sales.Total as balance
from
products
left join (select(product_id,SUM(pieces) as Total from purchases group by product_id)) purchases on products.id = purchases.product_id
left join (select(product_id,SUM(pieces) as Total from sales group by product_id)) sales on products.id = sales.product_id
```

Comment: the query does not work. there is some error.when I run the query mysql says -syntax error, near 'as Total from purchase group by product_id)) purchase on pr' at line 8